# python inter-process mutex for arbitrary processes

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, pthreads, python-multiprocessing

I need to `mutex` several processes running `python` on a `linux` host.

They processes are not spawned in a way I control (to be clear, they are my code), so i cannot use `multithreading.Lock`, at least as I understand it.  The resource being synchronized is a series of reads/writes to two separate internal services, which are old, stateful, not designed for concurrent/transactional access, and out of scope to modify.

a couple approaches I'm familiar with but rejected so far:

- In native code using `shmget` / `pthread_mutex_lock` (eg create a `pthread` mutex by well-known string name, in shared memory provided by the OS).  Im hoping to not have to use/add a `ctypes` wrapper for this (or ideally have any low-level constructs visible at all here for this high-level app).
- Using one of the `lock file` libraries such as `fasteners` would work - but requiring any *particular* file system access is awkward (the library/approach could use it robustly under the hood, but ideally my client code is abstracted from that).

Is there a preferred way to accomplish this in python (under linux; bonus points for cross-platform)?

Comment: I suggest to add some background information about your processes. What will the processes do? What resources need locking against concurrent access?

Comment: The next method that comes to mind is to use queues or pipes/sockets within your python code? Have the processes wait until a monitoring thread sends a task through the communication system. Is this not a possibility?

Comment: use a named semaphore: https://pypi.org/project/posix-ipc/

Comment: [here's](https://github.com/ralexander-phi/semaphore_win_ctypes) a wrapper for windows semaphores, but I haven't used it personally...

Comment: @Aaron - that looks promising i'll give that a shot.  Probably a candidate for an answer (although it's a very small project, there is a component to my question that is, OUTside of process pools (where `multiprocessing.Lock` is relevant), is there a most common way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options for synchronizing non-child processes:

1. [Use a remote manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager). I'm not super familiar with this process, but the docs has at least a simple example.
2. create a simple server with your own protocol (rather than a manager): something like a socket server on the loopback address for bouncing simple messages around.
3. use the filesystem: https://pypi.org/project/filelock/
4. On posix compliant systems, there's a rather straightforward wrapper for IPC constructs [posix-ipc](https://pypi.org/project/posix-ipc/). I also found a [wrapper for windows semaphores](https://github.com/ralexander-phi/semaphore_win_ctypes), but it's not quite as simple (though also not difficult per-say). In both cases your program would use a well known string "name" to access / create the mutex. In both cases, care / error checking is needed to handle creation of the mutex properly (see things like `O_CREX` flag...)